# Gitlab detect secret artifacts can not get in another stage

Tags: security, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

i am trying the gitlab default secret detection option.

here is `Gitlab CI` file i am trying

```
include:
    - template: Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
    - test

test:
  stage: test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      secret_detection: gl-secret-detection-report.json
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls
    - cat gl-secret-detection-report.json
```

i am not getting the file as artifacts.

error i am getting is :

```
cat: can't open 'gl-secret-detection-report.json': No such file or directory
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

however in default stage of Gitlab it is creating the file

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:03
Uploading artifacts...
gl-secret-detection-report.json: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "secret_detection" to coordinator... ok  id=1asdfas239 responseStatus=201 Created token=jT28Z-ot
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

so `secret_detection` stage is working which is default using template.

Comment: I got the same problem. Were you able to resolve this issue? According to the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/ the artifacts should be available in Merge request widget, Pipeline security report, Vulnerability Report. In my case they are not